# Как реализовать читалку для iOS?

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Добрый день. Прошу помощи в написании читалки для ios.

Ситуация такая. На нашем сервере лежат книги в HTML. Их нужно загружать на ios устройство и в  удобном для чтения виде предоставлять пользователю. Т.е., как в любой нормальной читалке, нужна навигация по главам, грамотный перенос строк и т.д.

Т.к. книги в HTML с подключенными к нему стилями, отформатированы. В общем, уже приведены к человеческому виду. Я решил, что в  `UIPageViewController` страницы будут отображаться через `UIWebView`. Проблема в том, что непонятно, как в этом случае управлять строками в книге. Как сделать, чтоб они правильно переносились с одной странице на другую и т.д.?

Я надеюсь, что понятно объяснил что мне нужно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если результат использования только UIWebView вас не устраивает, прийдется изобретать. Судя по тому что книги уже отформатированы, то прийдется использовать какие-то решения на базе JavaScript или парсить HTML/CSS самостоятельно и преобразовывать в свой DSL (примером может служить Opera со своим Turbo или Pocket с режимом чтения). Всё зависит от требований и возможностей.